# How can you fire a 'Media Key' event in Java?

Tags: keyboard, media-player, java

Media keys can be hardware or vendor specific, unlike the normal keyboard keys, so they do not appear to be widely supported - especially in the JDK.

Regardless, can a media key event be fired within Java so that an open media player will respond as if the user has pressed the Play/Pause button on their keyboard, thus enacting a play/pause on the current media?

If no Java specific answers are available, I would still be interested to see any solutions for non-platform independent languages.

All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JNI to call a small C Function or maybe you can use the Java Robot class.

Have a look at:

[Simulate a Keypress WinAPI - keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[List of Virtual Keycodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response - Not perfect, but a reasonable solution for now. Furthermore, *java.awt.Robot* does not *appear* to support media keys, as it requires *java.awt.event.KeyEvent* which doesn't have static ints for the media keys.